# getElementById and JQuery not returning same result

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, jquery-selectors

I'm not getting the same result when I use JQuery vs javascript functions.

This is the HTML

```
<form id="testform">
  <div id="FormContainerID"></div>
  <input type="button" id="y" value="Button" />
  <div id="ListContainerID"></div>
</form>
```

Here is the Javascript

```
01   var Form = document.getElementById('y').form;
02 //var Form = $('#y').closest('form');
03   alert(Form);
```

When Activating row 1, I get a legal form object. The Alert says "object HTMLFormElement" and everything works fine.

But if I use row 02 instead, Alert says "object Object" and then I ofcourse get errors becaus it isn't a real Form object.

Why is JQuery not returning the correct Object?
I get the same result with Chrome and IE8.

**[EDIT]**
I'm using JQuery version: jquery-1.5.1.min

**[SOLUTION]**
Thank you for clearing this up. I Changed the code to:

`var Form = $('#'+fChildID).closest('form')[0];`

...and now it works as a charm.
Vivek Goel was the first to answer, so creds to him. I voted up you other guys that explained the JQuery instance model.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with jquery use

```
 alert(Form[0]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dvCtr/

Comment: I can't find any documentation about .closest() should return an array. Is it always returning an array, or have I misunderstood something fundamental?

Comment: @Max: It's not an array, it's a `jQuery` instance (an object created via the `jQuery.fn.init` constructor function), which is a wrapper around the matched set of DOM elements. And yes, jQuery *always* returns a `jQuery` instance, whether there are zero matching elements, one, or 1,000 (or more).

Answer (score 4):

jQuery returns a `jQuery` instance when you use it to look things up, not the raw DOM element. The `jQuery` instance is a wrapper around the set of matched elements, and allows you to apply set-based operations to the elements. This is one of the absolute fundamentals of using jQuery.

You can also access the raw elements if you like using array-like notation — `[0]`, `[1]`, etc., up to `.length - 1`. So in your case, since you're getting just one element, it would be `Form[0]`. If your code matched multiple form elements, it would be `Form[1]` for the second one, `Form[2]` for the third one, etc. (Using the `[]` notation is surprisingly hard to find in the documentation, though, one of the gaps in my view; in the old days you used the `get` method, but you only need that now if you're using its special handling for negative indexes.)

You frequently don't need to access the raw elements at all. You haven't said what you're going to do with the form once you have it, but if you were to (say) submit it, just call the `submit` function on the `jQuery` instance, and it will submit the form. If you wanted to get an attribute from it, there's the `attr` jQuery function (so for instance, `val = Form.attr("action")`).

jQuery is very set-based, but it's assymetrical, which feels weird at first but works fairly well in practice. When *getting* a value, functions usually get the value from the *first* matched element only. When *setting* a value, functions usually set it on *all* the matched elements.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the jquery statement is returning a jquery object and not a form object.
You need something like Form[0] to access the form element.

Comment: As per [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .closest() method allows us to search through these elements and their ancestors in the DOM tree and construct **a new jQuery object** from the matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> var form = $("#y").parent

this should return the parent of `y`in the DOM tree

Comment: `parent` is a function, not a property. And you're changing his code, but not -- with respect -- usefully (as `parent()` *also* returns a jQuery object, not a raw DOM element, just like `closest()` does). Perhaps he wants to be flexible and allow the designers to put additional layers between the form and the input element.